# Is comment html just restricted to <!-- or can I use another variation of it?

Tags: html

As the title says I want something like `<!++This is a comment ++>` .
I did some experiments on it and it didn't display the text as it made it a comment. My question is if I use it than the default one would it have any problems in my html or webpage?

```
<!++ This is a comment ++>
<p>Test</p>
```

Will output : Test

Example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5b0wpyot/).

Comment: you can use `<!--++ This is a comment ++-->`

Answer (score 3):

> Comments must start with the four character sequence U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN, U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS (`<!--`). Following this sequence, the comment may have text, with the additional restriction that the text must not start with a single ">" (U+003E) character, nor start with a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) followed by a ">" (U+003E) character, nor contain two consecutive U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS characters (--), nor end with a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-). Finally, the comment must be ended by the three character sequence U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (-->).
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comments

So, no, you can't use alternative characters. The reason nothing shows up when you used `<!++` is that the browser attempts to interpret that as an HTML tag (because it starts with `<`). It will end up as some garbage on the DOM which may or may not have any consequences; but it's not going to be interpreted as *comment* which is specified to have *no* consequences at all.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!!
Quite an insight on it..
I'll take notice of it :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML documentations is specific with regards to their syntax in making comments. I wonder what purpose you have for making variations in your comments but I advice you to just comply with the syntax of html to avoid problems in your code. You may also try this to make your comments neat:

```
<!--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
                               Your comment
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@-->
```